# The conversion of the varchar value overflowed an int column in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm getting an error with a query to get data... The error message is: Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1: The conversion of the varchar value overflowed an int column...
I cant resolve this problem, so if any one can help me, thanks in advance, Here is My Sql:

This happens when I inserted 3 new joins in the query, I made them BOLD, otherwise it works perfectly...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   ACR_ART_ID, DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT AS CRITERIA_DES_TEXT,
   COALESCE(DES_TEXTS2.TEX_TEXT, ACR_VALUE) AS CRITERIA_VALUE_TEXT,
   (DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT + ': ' + COALESCE(DES_TEXTS2.TEX_TEXT, ACR_VALUE)) AS CEL_OPIS
FROM              
   Inventory.dbo.ARTICLE_CRITERIA
LEFT JOIN 
   Inventory.dbo.DESIGNATIONS AS DESIGNATIONS2 ON DESIGNATIONS2.DES_ID = ACR_KV_DES_ID 
LEFT JOIN 
   Inventory.dbo.DES_TEXTS AS DES_TEXTS2 ON DES_TEXTS2.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS2.DES_TEX_ID
LEFT JOIN 
   Inventory.dbo.CRITERIA ON CRI_ID = ACR_CRI_ID 
LEFT JOIN 
   Inventory.dbo.DESIGNATIONS ON DESIGNATIONS.DES_ID = CRI_DES_ID
LEFT JOIN 
   Inventory.dbo.DES_TEXTS ON DES_TEXTS.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS.DES_TEX_ID
INNER JOIN 
   Inventory.dbo.ART_LOOKUP al ON ARTICLE_CRITERIA.ACR_ART_ID = al.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER
    AND al.ARL_KIND in (1,3)
INNER JOIN 
   Inventory.dbo.ARTICLES a ON al.ARL_ART_ID = a.ART_ID and (a.ART_SUP_ID=21 or a.ART_SUP_ID=11091)
INNER JOIN 
   Inventory.dbo.SUPPLIERS ON SUPPLIERS.SUP_ID = ART_SUP_ID**
WHERE  
   (DESIGNATIONS.DES_LNG_ID IS NULL OR DESIGNATIONS.DES_LNG_ID = 25)
   AND (DESIGNATIONS2.DES_LNG_ID IS NULL OR DESIGNATIONS2.DES_LNG_ID = 25);
```

Comment: Can u check the max of ID in your table

Comment: The bold part of the query did not come out, but looking at the edit I think it was supposed to be the last three joins. Can you add them one at a time to let people know which one makes the query fail, then check the varchar field in there which is likely to be case to an int (to see if it has values clearly out of range). Then perhaps an explicit cast to make the query work using different types.

Comment: It sounds like at least one of the joins is joining a `varchar` col to an `int` col. The `varchar` col is implicitly converted to an `int` and is overflowing (i.e. is larger than 2,147,483,647). To resolve this try casting the columns to `bigint`. It may also be worth refactoring the design to no store integers as strings.

Comment: there are two asterix at the end of a "Inventory.dbo.SUPPLIERS ON SUPPLIERS.SUP_ID = ART_SUP_ID**" is that just a mistake or something you need to remove from your query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Commented by @T I

> The varchar col is implicitly converted to an int and is overflowing (i.e. is >larger than 2,147,483,647). To resolve this try casting the columns to bigint

you can cast column value data type as

```
select cast( max(columnname) AS bigint)+1 from atable ;
```

But if you will get a varchar than it will fail,
with error 
So it is better to change your DB schema.
Use this approach only if you are sure that only numeric string will be present.